# ToggleButton Content binding to its state

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

I need exactly was is solved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986727/togglebutton-checkbox-content-depending-on-its-checked-state), unfortunately it is for Silverlight and I was not able to make that "Interactivity" libraries to work.

I have a `ToggleButton` and I want to change the `Content` property to "Hello" when it's checked "Good bye" when it's unchecked. Changing it manually is not an option for me in this case, as the change of the state can be done from multiple sources.

I think that an Converter might be needed for this task, and I've seen converters to Visibility but not to string.

EDIT: I've thought about putting both words in a stackpanel and switch the visibility Visible/Collapsed bound to the state:

```
         <ToggleButton.Content>
          <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="Hello" Visibility="{Binding ...}"/>
              <TextBlock Text="GoodBye"/>
          </StackPanel>
      </ToggleButton.Content>
```

Comment: You could use 'Commands' for this (declaratively in XAML)

Comment: You need a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity library and that solution you indicated for Silverlight will work in WPF as well.

Comment: And probably `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` too

Answer (score 7):

You can use Triggers:

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Hello" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Good bye" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

If you want to use System.Windows.Interactivity.dll you can find it in Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) ([download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801)).

Comment: That works great but I can't use it because I'm using a interface template and if I change the Style, the default theme is shown. Is there a way to add those triggers AND maintain the current visuals?

Comment: @Sturm yes of course. You should check `BasedOn` property in Style: `<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource tb}" TargetType="ToggleButton" >`

Comment: tb is supposed to be the name of my current template?

Comment: @Sturm your current style. Can you paste this style?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a BooleanToSalutation:

```
public class BooleanToSalutationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Boolean)
        {
            return (bool)value ? "Hello" : "Good bye";
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return ((string)value) == "Hello";
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```